# Using jqueryUi.resizeable() with AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a DOM element in one of my templates that I want to make resizable using jqueryUi. The long and short is that I have a `<div>` element in my template called "test".... Other than that I have tried adding scripts to actually do the resizing in multiple places but I have gotten myself completely turned around.

I thought at one point that a directive may be the proper thing to do ... or that since im using jqueryui and not really angular type stuff that I could get away with putting a script into my template, or controller ... but they have all failed for me for multiple reasons so far ...

anyway .. back to square one ...

Within an *angularJs application* how does one actually implement the `resizable()` functionality from the jqueryui library .

As an addition I have taken a look at the answer below and worked up the following code:

html:

```
<div resizable on-resize="resize()"> Test </div>
```

directive:

```
angular.module('tffullscreen.directives').

directive('resizable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
        callback: '&onResize'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.resizable();
        elem.on('resizestop', function (evt, ui) {
            if (scope.callback) { scope.callback(); }
        });
        window.e = elem;
    }
    };
});
```

controller:

```
$scope.resize = function () {
    console.log("RESIZED FUNCTION CALLED IN CONTROLLER");
};
```

The issue here is that this is what gets rendered on my screen when the template is loaded:

```
<div resizable="" on-resize="resize()" class="ng-isolate-scope ui-resizable"> 
Test 
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div></div>
```

This seems like what i should see ... except that All i see in the window is the word test with no resize box visible ... and when I inspect the elements that get added to the DOM all of them have a width but 0 height.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For such stuff, a directive is always the right way to go.
To make an element resizable (with an optional callback), you should implement a directive like this:

```
app.directive('resizable', function () {
    var resizableConfig = {...};

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            callback: '&onResize'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, elem) {
            elem.resizable(resizableConfig);
            elem.on('resizestop', function () {
                if (scope.callback) scope.callback();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then, in the HTML:

```
<div resizable on-resize="someFunction()">Hello, world !</div>
```

---

If you need varying resizable configurations, you can pass that to the isolate scope using an attribute.

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/EE63X/)**.

Comment: see above please ... i know this is close

Comment: THis answer works ... i still have some tweaking to do of wrapper classes but it works ... Thank You

Comment: This works for me if I wrap elem with $(..): 
                    var el = $(elem);
                    el.resizable();
                    el.on('resizestop', function (evt, ui) {
                        if (scope.callback) { scope.callback(); }
                    });

Comment: @Vitamon: If you are using jQuery with Angular (i.e. including jQuery **before** Angular), then `elem` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: @ExpertSystem thank you for this answer, it helped me. I am wondering how I can pass a parameter into the callback function. This: scope.callback('hi'); does not work. When I pass a parameter into the callback function it shows as undefined. Thank you, Mila.

Comment: @mila: You should take a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) on how to pass arguments to isolate scope expressions (e.g. functions). Basically, you need to change `someFunction()` to `someFunction(arg1, arg2,...)` and then call it like this: `$scope.callback({arg1: 'hi', arg2: 'something else',...})`